# Is it possible to open everything in a Unity drawer by a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, launcher

I have started using [Drawers](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/add-stacks-to-unity-launcher-with.html).

I have a drawer that contains dragged and dropped files. I want to open everything in the drawer via a shortcut key. Is this possible?

I tried to select all items in the drawer, but I could not. If it were possible, I would hit `Enter` to launch all items in the drawer.